# Реестр \Policies

Tags: windows, реестр

Какие и кому установлены разрешения на доступ к разделам реестра HKEY_CURRENT_USER  и HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies и почему ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Разрешения.

Ответ на вопрос кому установлены разрешения, можно получить просмотрев самостоятельно назначенные права на ветви.
В стандартной конфигурации Windows используются  3 встроенные группы пользователей:
Restricted,Administrators,SYSTEM.
Также права имеются у пользователя, к чьей учетной записи относятся эти ветви.

1.1 HKCU

У пользователей Restricted имеются права только на чтение, у админов и системы - полные. Конечно же, пользователь своей ветви имеет права на изменение своей ветви.

1.2 HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies.

Однако, исходя из того, что групповой политикой могут управлять только админы - напрямую или через системные процессы, - следует, что к ветке Polices пользователи должны иметь права ТОЛЬКО на чтение. Запись - только Administrators и SYSTEM.

2. Почему

Прямой ответ на вопрос "почему", можно получить изучив документацию для разработчиков. Вообще, это соотносится с моделью контроля управления доступом к объектам Windows. Я думаю, полный ответ тут могут дать и другие участники.